# Como faço para que o programa mostre todas as combinações e depois o número de combinações que foram formadas?

Tags: python

O que já tenho até agora:

```
from itertools import permutations
word = str(input())
for subset in permutations(word,len(word)):
    print(subset)
```

Comment: Acho que não. Tem que saber que fonte está sendo utilizada no output, o tamanho da fonte e o tamanho da janela do output. Pq precisa disso?

Comment: Estou usando análise combinatória em listas e como em cada linha tem uma combinação diferente, eu pensei que seria mais fácil fazer isso do que usar o fatorial do número de letras para descobrir quantos combinações existem.

Comment: Se são listas, não seria mais fácil contar o número de elementos delas?

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo?

Comment: Coloca o seu problema. É muito difícil corrigir uma solução que ficou ruim. É melhor te dar outra ideia

Comment: É complicado porque você precisa saber o tamanho da janela, fonte, quantidade de elementos das listas e etc. É bem mais fácil contar a quantidade de itens na lista ao invés disto tudo.

Comment: @JoãoVictor, editei minha pergunta, esse é o programa.

Comment: E desculpe pela demora.

Comment: Parece que você já tem praticamente o que precisa. Ele já mostra as combinações possíveis, certo? Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Gostaria que o programa dissesse no final: 'Existem x combinações possíveis.'

Comment: Amigo, pode dizer se a solução que eu dei funcionou?

Comment: Adicionei a linha que você disse no fora do loop e depois de mostrar todas as combinações possíveis deu esse erro:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 5, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'itertools.permutations' has no len()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para saber o número de combinações, basta você salvá-las todas em uma lista e verificar após o seu tamanho.

```
from itertools import permutations

word = str(input())
sequences = list(permutations(word,len(word)))

for subset in sequences:
    print(subset)

print("Número de sequências:", len(sequences))
```

Se a lista for muito grande e não quiser armazená-la toda em memória, basta criar um contador auxiliar:

```
from itertools import permutations

word = str(input())
sequences = permutations(word,len(word))
total = 0

for subset in sequences:
    total += 1
    print(subset)

print("Número de sequências:", total)
```

Comment: Gostei da resposta, mas se permutations() retorna um objeto iterável, não basta fazer len(permutations())?

Comment: @JoãoVictor Não, pois o retorno é um gerador. É iterável, mas é impossível inferir qual o seu tamanho sem percorrê-lo por completo. Convertê-lo para uma lista faz isso implicitamente.

Comment: O método len() não percorre ele por completo?

Comment: @JoãoVictor não, pois seria um erro de implementação. Um gerador só pode ser "percorrido" uma vez e seus valores anteriores são perdidos. Se a função `len` percorresse-o, não poderíamos utilizá-lo mais após isso - e nem antes, pois o `len` calcularia errado a quantidade de elementos.

Comment: Acho que entendi seu ponto. Mas o fato da função permutations() retornar o mesmo resultado depois do código todo do colega aí, não faz com que a minha solução que dei abaixo funcione?

Comment: @JoãoVictor tentei criar um exemplo: https://ideone.com/5vvo3J. Sua solução apresenta erro de tipo dizendo que o retorno de `permutations` não pode ser utilizado em `len`. Mesmo assim terá que converter para uma lista (ou tupla) para que seja possível inferir sobre seu tamanho.

Comment: Olha o que eu quis dizer http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_JzGSo08mhb_0.py

Answer (score 2):

Acho que adicionar essa linha no final do codigo fora do loop funciona:

```
print(len(permutations(word,len(word))))
```

### Editado:

A solução anterior não funciona, portanto eu utilizaria a mesma solução do Woss:

```
from itertools import permutations
word = str(input())
count = 0
for subset in permutations(word,len(word)):
    count += 1
    print(subset)
print(count)
```

Comment: João, você chegou a testar esse código? Ele dá erro de tipo dizendo que o retorno da função `permutations` não pode ser utilizado na função `len`, ou seja, sua solução não funciona.

Comment: Realmente não funciona. :(